# Use Case. Google Maps is an external actor?

Tags: google-maps, use-case

I'm writing a use case where the user clicks the map to select his/her location and draw a marker in the map.

In this use case is google maps an external actor?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In this use case is google maps an external actor?

It depends on what the Use Case is.  But unlikely.

Use Cases are meant to describe what the User wants to achieve.  How you realise that goal is 'implementation detail'.  The point is to help you focus on understanding the User's needs and goals instead of getting too caught up in the technology.

So first off, how would you name the Use Case?  I'd guess it would be something like "Mark Current Location".  Assuming so, google maps is part of your solution - not external to it.  So it shouldn't exist as an external actor.

hth.

Comment: Yes, the use case name is similiar to "Mark Current Location".
Thanks!